# Storing a derived pointer to method

Tags: c++, inheritance, function-pointers

I want to create a class, that has pointer to one of its methods as attribute. Then there should be a method, that is used to set this pointer.

```
class A {
    private:
        void (A::*curr_f)();
    public:

        void set(void (A::*f)()) {
            curr_f = f;
        }
};
```

Problems start when I try to create inherited class and set the pointer to one of its methods.

```
class B : A {
    public:
        void main() {
            set(&B::new_function);
        };
        void new_function() {};
};
```

Errors I'm getting are quite straightforward, but still, I have no idea how to solve this.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘B::set(void (B::*)())’
note: candidate is:
note: void A::set(void (A::*)())
note: no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘void (B::*)()’ to ‘void (A::*)()’
```

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? i.e. What's a use case?

Comment: The whole project is a library for discrete simulation. Class A is really a class Process. User of the library will create its own inherited class, for example class MyProcess, with methods MyProcess::part1, MyProcess::part2, MyProcess::part3... In every method, he should be able to set, which method will follow. Then every time process is planned, i get pointer to MyProcess object and i should execute the right method (method in curr_f).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. `A` has not method `new_function` and you're lying to the compiler. You have three ways

### 1.

Move `new_function` to `A` and pass `A::new_function` (as `virtual` is preferred).

```
class A
{
    void (A::*curr_f)();
public:
    void set(void (A::*f)())
    {
        curr_f = f;
    }
    virtual void new_function() {};
};

class B : A
{
public:
    void main()
    {
        set(&A::new_function);
    };
    void new_function() {};
};
```

### 2.

Forward `B` declaration and store `B::*` in the `A`:

```
class B;

class A
{
    void (B::*curr_f)();
public:
    void set(void (B::*f)())
    {
        curr_f = f;
    }
};

class B : A
{
public:
    void main()
    {
        set(&B::new_function);
    }
    void new_function() {}
};
```

### 3.

You can try template based ways, like [the curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

```
template <typename D>
class A
{
    void (D::*curr_f)();
public:
    void set(void (D::*f)())
    {
        curr_f = f;
    }
};

class B : public A<B>
{
public:
    void main()
    {
        set(&B::new_function);
    }
    void new_function() {}
};
```

Comment: The thing is that class A is part of my library and class B should be user defined with lots of user defined functions. So first two ways don't work for me. But the third one is just what I needed. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

```
You can have the code like this:


   #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class A {
  protected:
    void (T::*curr_f)();
  public:

    virtual void set(void (T::*f)()) {
      curr_f = f;
      cout<<"Set in A"<<endl;
      T obj;
      (obj.*curr_f)();
    }

    virtual void new_function() {cout<<"in A"<<endl;};

};


class B :public A<B> {

  public:
    void func() {
      set(&B::new_function);
    };
    void new_function() {cout<<"in B"<<endl;};

};

int main()
{

  B obj;
  obj.func();

}
```